# Is djangoappengine (django-nonrel) production worthy?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I'm thinking of hosting an app on app engine, and I already started building it in native django. Is it crazy to use djangoappengine (django-nonrel) for a production product? Is it proven?

Comment: do you have a specific reason to not use the (simpler) SQL version? If so, do it! If not, well, probably don't.

Comment: I think NoSQL makes sense for this project. I don't need a lot of joins. I like the simplicity of NoSQL.

Comment: as django abstracts all that away.....

Comment: If you need scalability, reliability and don't like server administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be [available at least since 2010](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel) and [acknowledged by Google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Introduction). So I'd say it's pretty solid.

Comment: I noticed that. It did give me some confidence to see it in the google docs.

Answer (score 0):

django-appengine is widely used in production by companies such as [Potato London](https://p.ota.to/), have a look at their porfolio, you'll find some pretty solid stuff.

You do need to realize that there are quite substancial diferences with a vanilla Django SQL installation, especially in the ORM, many complex queries will not be available as JOINs are not supported natively. There are workarounds for most problems but they're a bit harder to wrap your head around if you never used non-relational databases or Datastore.

Make sure you read the [documentation on Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore) and the [django-appengine DB documentation](http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/db.html) and judge if it's worth the trouble.

Also worth mention these two packages from AllButtonsPressed that help a *lot* [dbindexer](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-dbindexer) and [nonrel-search](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/nonrel-search).

Comment: Thanks. That's nice to see. I just wanted to make sure that no one thought this was a a terrible idea.